# Upgraded to php 7 magento 1.9. No orders, customers or products are showing in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I've upgraded my php to 7 since my pci compliance scan said I needed to. So now my site is not working properly at all. I've tried a few edits from others and nothing is helping.

The product, orders and customers tables are not showing. The heading is there but  nothing under them.

Edited to add: The tables are not showing on the front end either. Header, template and category selection is working fine. No products show just an empty page between the header and footer.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Delete var folder,  run indexing and delete browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't see why running PHP 5.6 would be a problem with PCI compliance. We have several sites running PHP 5.6 (in UK) and never had any issue with PCI compliance (or never got notified).

By default Magento 1.x doesn't support PHP 7, if however you do need to make it compatible with PHP 7 there is an open source [PHP 7 compatibility extension](http://inchoo.net/magento/its-alive/) from Inchoo that could give you a massive helping hand. If after installing extension you still face issues you can try to get in tuch with guys at Inchoo who I heard could be quite helpful at times :)

Good Luck.